# Resize image into view - react native

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, resize

I'm wondering if it's possible to resize an image to fit it inside a view.

This is what I have now

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Image
        source={headerImage}    
      />

    </View>
    <Text style={styles.basicText}>text</Text>
  </View>
```

---

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      },
      header: {
        height: 200, 
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      background: {
        width: null,
        height: null
      },
      image: {

      }
```

I want to make the image fit into the header view.

Comment: you can try with `resizeMode` http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/image.html

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Moti Azu's answer, you need to also set the resizeMode.

```
image: {
  flex:1,
  height: null,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
  width: null,
}
```

If it does not seem to work, make sure that your `View` with style `container` has a width.

Answer (score 0):

Try below style

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <Image  style={styles.image}
      source={headerImage}    
    />

   </View>
  <Text style={styles.basicText}>text</Text>
</View>
```

Style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  header: {
    height: 200, 
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  background: {
    width: null,
    height: null
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  }
})
```

Refer the react native image property

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/image.html#props

or use resizeMode in image Props

Answer (score -1):

Add flex:1 to the image, it will stretch all over it's container.

```
 image: {
     flex: 1
 }
```